# Unmet Peer Dependency -- firebase-admin@5.9.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use the [messaging.send()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#send) method recently released in [Admin Node.js SDK 5.9.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#5.9.0) and described in [this Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/02/firebase-cloud-messaging-v1-now.html).

To ensure I had the latest SDKs, I followed the [Cloud Functions setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize) and executed this command in my project's functions folder:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
```

The command completed with this warning:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@5.9.0
`-- firebase-functions@0.8.1

npm WARN firebase-functions@0.8.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.8.1 but none was installed.
```

How can this be corrected while still retaining `firebase-admin@5.9.0`?

Or can the warning be safely ignored?  I found that even with the unmet peer dependency, I was able to successfully deploy and run my cloud function that uses the new `send()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vast majority of the time, you can safely ignore this warning.  It just means that the `firebase-functions` module was published with a requirement for 5.8.1, but you forced a newer version.  If there are no breaking changes between 5.8.1 and the new version, there won't be a problem.

If your functions run fine, just ignore the warning.  I've never heard of a problem myself.